# MSSQL-How to join a table and for those null values, specifically use one item from the joined tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

Please check the tables below:

When table 1 left join Table 2 on Column ItemName, for Pear and Orange, the Coef column will be null. How can I get those non mapped items to all match for ItemName = *Others* in Table 2?

Currently, I am using temp table to filter those null items , put the correct coef and then union with the mapped item results to get the final Table 3.

Are there any better ways to achieve this?

Table 1:

```
ItemName  |  Cost  |
Apple     |  1     |
Banana    |  2     |
Pear      |  3     |
Orange    |  4     |
```

Table 2:

```
ItemName  |  Coef  |
Apple     |  0.1   |
Banana    |  0.2   |
Others    |  0.8   |
```

Expected Results:

```
ItemName  |  Cost  |  Coef  |
Apple     |  1     |  0.1   |
Banana    |  2     |  0.2   |
Pear      |  3     |  0.8   |
Orange    |  4     |  0.8   |
```

Comment: Which database are you really using, MySQL or SQL Server?  Please tag corectly

Answer (score 3):

You could `cross join` your result with that single row and take the first non-null value:

```
SELECT     t1.itemname, t1.cost, COALESCE(t2.coef, def.coef)
FROM       t1
LEFT JOIN  t2 ON t1.itemname = t2.itemname
CROSS JOIN (SELECT coef
            FROM   t2
            WHERE  itemname = 'Others') def
```

Comment: Minor spelling: `itername` => `itemname`

Comment: Works great! Thx

Answer (score 3):

You can use two left joins:

```
select t1.*,
       coalesce(t2.coef, t2o.coef) as coef
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.itemname = t2.itemname left join
     t2 t2o
     on t2o.itemname = 'Others';
```

Comment: Minor spelling: `'others'` => `'Others'`

Comment: Works great! Thx